# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'camera')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I want to detect a collision after a MouseMove, so I implement the Raycaster from Three js, but I'm getting an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'camera')

Code:

```
  bindIFrameMousemove(iframe){
  iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  const mouse = new Vector2();
  var clRect = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
  var evt = new CustomEvent('mousemove', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false});
  const clientX = (window.TouchEvent && event instanceof TouchEvent) ? 
  event.changedTouches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
  const clientY = (window.TouchEvent && event instanceof TouchEvent) ? 
  event.changedTouches[0].clientY : event.clientY;
  const x = ( clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  const y = - ( clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  iframe.dispatchEvent(evt);
   event.preventDefault();
   mouse.x= ( clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y =  - ( clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
   Raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, this.context.camera );
   const intersects = Raycaster.getIntersectObjects(this.scene.children ,true );
   console.log(intersects)

   if (intersects.length > 0) {
     console.log("intersects !!");
   }
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.context` is `undefined` because `this` is not the global `this`. You should google the difference.
to solve your problem you should use an arrow function

```js
iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('mousemove',(event) => {
```

Comment: this is what i had when i changed to an arrow function : three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.Raycaster.setFromCamera is not a function

Comment: well that'a another problem down the line. Maybe create a new stackoverlow question.
We don't know what Raycaster is... setFromCamera is a static function or what?